# JavaScript - uniquely updating properties in prototyped object literals

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I'm just now getting into instantiating JavaScript object literals using a prototype constructor, but am a bit confused by the rules of inheritance/reflection which apply to my case.

Essentially my problem is that the original object that's being prototyped has several tiers of properties/values:

```
var protoObj = {  
  prop1: {  
    first : 1,
    second : 2,
    third : {  
      a : 'foo',
      b : 'bar',
      c : {  
        'love': true,  
        'babies': false,
        'joy': undefined
      }
    } 
  },  
  prop2 : true       
};
```

...where all but a select few of these properties will remain the same (and should be dynamically updated) in all child objects.

I can update or create new top-tier properties for the child objects without affecting the original prototype object just fine:

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
  Object.create = function(o){
    var F = function(){};
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
  };
}

var someObj = Object.create(protoObj);

someObj.prop2 = false;   
//protoObj.prop2 remains true

someObj.prop3 = [x,y,z];
//new property, unique to someObj (i.e. protoObj remains untouched)
```

If, however, I want to set a unique value for the deeply entrenched property `'joy'` in `someObj`, I can't seem to do so without redefining `protoObj` itself or breaking `someObj`'s delegation chain back to its prototype:

```
someObj.prop1.third.c['joy'] = 'found';
//does not *directly* update someObj
//instead ends up setting the value of protoObj's property 'joy' to be 'found'


someObj.prop1 = {
  first : 1,
  second : 2,
  third : {  
    a : 'foo',
    b : 'bar',
    c : {  
      'love': true,  
      'babies': false,
      'joy': 'found'
    }
  }
};
//explicitly sets the above values in someObj.prop1 (including 'joy'), but breaks
//the prototypal link back to protoObj for all data in someObj.prop1 as well
```

I suspect that I'm  either overlooking an incredibly simple solution or altogether out of luck, but I'd be much obliged to hear from you all on this regardless. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the code that produces someObj from protoObj please?
In fact, how do you prototype all that stuff?

Comment: @Pierre - updated in the second code block.

Comment: He doesn't need to change anything, his question is pretty clear. The problem is that his prototype contains a reference to an object, and so changes to that object will be visible from all instances of the class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're altogether out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you are partially out of luck.

Long answer. When you create an object prototyped from another, you are telling the JavaScript interpreter that the derived object "looks like" the ancestor object. When you read from a property, the interpreter knows that it can walk the prototype chain if need be. So for:

```
var x = someObj.prop2;
```

It first looks at the `someObj` object. Does it have a property called `prop2`? No, so go look at the prototype object. Does it have a property called `prop2`? Yes, so return that value.

When you set a property, it gets set in the object directly. No walking the prototype chain here. So:

```
someObj.prop2 = true;
```

means that the `prop2` property gets created in `someObj` and is set to true. After this point, when you read `prop2` you will get the direct value and no walking the prototype chain.

Now with `prop1` the same thing happens. Read it from `someObj`

```
var x = someObj.prop1;
```

and you will get the object `prop1` from the prototype object, since it doesn't exist in `someObj`.

But watch out: this is a reference to `propObj`'s property. Change its properties and you will change them for `propObj`. If you do need to make changes to `prop1` such that those are only visible in `someObj`, you will have to prototype that object too:

```
var someObj = Object.create(propObj);
someObj.prop1 = Object.create(propObj.prop1);
someObj.prop1.first = 42;
```

Here, that last line will alter the value of `first` in `someObj.prop1` and not the value in `propObj`. If you need to go deeper, then prototype the next level down and so on so forth.

Comment: Sort of an annoying quirk, but I suppose it's there for good reason and not too much trouble to work around. Anyway, this is great - many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think i got it.

Prototyping is used to share methods with all instances. It seems like you are trying to use prototype to give particular instance members to the derivated someObj object.

But to understand why it's a bad solution, here how prototyping works:

When JS try to **resolve** (retain that) a member reference on an object, if it does not find this member in the object, it looks in its prototype (and so on along the prototype chain).

So when you want to **read** someObj.prop1, JS does **not** find prop1 in someObj, it looks in its prototype protoObj, and find protoObj.prop1:

Thus said, it's totally normal that:

```
someObj.prop1.third.c['joy'] = 'found'
```

...modifies the prototype because someObj.prop1 **is resolved as** protoObj.prop1

The slightly detail you are ignoring is that in an affectation, JS doesn't necessary **resolve** the member. When you write stuff like:

```
someObj.stuff.other = 3
```

JS resolves someObj.stuff because you are asking *.other* on it.

But when you type:

```
someObj.stuff = 3
```

JS does **not** resolve anything!! It just affects *3* to the *stuff* member of *someObj* and dont care at all about the existence or nonexistence of *stuff* in *someObj* or in its prototype.

If *stuff* was effectively in the prototype, the new member of the same name masks the prototype one.

From now, you may understand that using the prototyping of JS to give member values to the instances is not a good solution at all. Instead, you should consider setting these members in the function constructor itself. For instance:

```
function MyObj() {
  this.prop1 = {first: 1, second: 2, third: {a: ...} }
  this.prop2 = true;
}
```

Obviously each instance has its own members distinct from protoObj ones.

If you want to use prototyping to provide some default and mutable values to your objects, and be able to "fork" a part of these values when you modify them through an instance (a sort of copy-on-write), this is just impossible in JavaScript.

Comment: "this is just impossible in JavaScript" <= that's wrong. boyetboy gave a solution at the end of his answer.

Comment: Glad he did! Thanks for giving it a crack.